# Delay and fadeout not working properly after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following AJAX call and after the AJAX call has been successful, I would like my `#success` message to delay and fadeout. As of now all it does is show up for maybe .2-.3 of a second and then it goes away faster than it came in.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.approve').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'userRequest_approve.php',
            data: {
                id: $(this).val(), //id
                status: 'Approved' //status
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //do something with the data that got returned
                $('#success').html('User Status Changed!');
                $('#success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
            },
            type: 'POST'
        });
    });
});
```

My form..

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="status">
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $pending_id; ?>' id='pending_id' />
    <?php if ($pending_firstname==t rue) { echo "Name - ". $pending_firstname . " " . $pending_lastname . "</br>" . "Username - ". $pending_username . "</br></br>" //echo print_r($_POST); ?>
</form>
<button class="approve" type="submit" form="status" name="approve" value="<?=$pending_id;?>">Approve</button>
```

I made a Fiddle for this... https://jsfiddle.net/jr7tuLep/

I am getting an error with it and I have no idea what it means, but I pasted into it the source code rather than php.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong with this? (I have the Jquery library in my file)

This is a little outside of my initial question, but with my AJAX call, is there a way to detect when something does not perform right and post a message with that?

Comment: Maybe try doing animations with CSS3? I fiddled a lot around with animations with jQuery a few years back. Since then I only use CSS Transitions as it works a lot smother, is in most browsers GPU accelerated and works a lot easier. Please tell me if i should show you what i mean

Comment: Please add the error message. I don't see it in your question.

Comment: Are you calling an AJAX function that is hosted in another domain? Is the success code being executed?

Comment: The error is extra `});`. You should read the console errors.

Comment: Fixed jsFiddle, working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/51pa1zgr/  So i'm not sure what are you expecting?

Comment: No, it is the same domain, I just made a php file to update something in my db.

Comment: The reason I have the extra `});` was for the document load

Comment: @A.Wolff whenever I put `return false` in it, it kills my Ajax call and doesn't perform my query. When I take the `return false` code out my script works, but the fadeout and delays doesn't work again.

Comment: Does any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please select the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

HTML:

```
<form id="status">
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='23' id='pending_id' />Name - john</br>Username - john</form>
<button class="approve" type="submit" form="status" name="approve" value="23">Approve</button>
<div id="success" style="color: red;"></div>
<br>
```

JS Code:

```
$('.approve').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html',
         type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: $(this).val(), //id
            status: 'Approved' //status
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //do something with the data that got returned
            $("#success").fadeIn();
            $("#success").show();
            $('#success').html('User Status Changed!');
            $('#success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
        },

    });
    return false;
});
```

You can manage errors in AJAX using the error property, just like you do with success. On the other hand, if you code at server-side decides something went wrong, you can return a boolean and an error message indicating what went wrong so you can display it to the user.

Comment: Something like this for the error? `try {
  throw new Error('Whoops!');
} catch (e) {
  alert(e.name + ': ' + e.message);
}`

Comment: If I leave in the `return false;` , my code dies and it does not perform the AJAX call. If I comment that out, the message does what it was doing from the beginning?

Comment: For the error, you add error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown); }

Comment: Do you know how I can change this so the delay and fadeout work and so my code doesn't break? The `return false;` is breaking the call. Where would I put the error message in this? This is my first Ajax call, so sorry if I sound very ignorant to it.

Comment: The code I provided works as is, it doesn't break with "return false". Try it on jsfiddle. Return false is a must because it avoids the form from being submitted.

Comment: The fadeout works when I have `return false` in it, but then my update query in my php file doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
$('#success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
```

with standard JavaScript timeout

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#success').fadeOut(400);
}, 5000);
```

In case you're not putting a delay between multiple jQuery functions (`$('#success').fadeIn(400).delay(500).fadeOut(600);`) it may be more appropriate to use the `setTimeout()` function instead.

https://api.jquery.com/delay/